# How to select column names manually from dropdown?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe without columns names. How to manually set column names from dropdown ipywidgets?

I have a dataframe without headers:

```
A B C 
D E F
G H I
```

I want to display dataframe in this presentation:

```
  dropdown dropdown dropdown
    A        B        C 
    D        E        F
    G        H        I
```

Where dropdown it is element allows to choose a column name from dropdown list.

Comment: Maybe there is way to do this (dropwodn) in HTML/JS ?

Comment: I need an iteraction with user when dataframe loaded user have to specify columns names

Comment: I can place one dropdown select and ask user choose value from this dropdown the same time as columns count

Comment: "from dropdown ipywidgets" Why not giving column names to your dataframe and then set the dropdown accordingly? I mean I'm not sure to understand. Show us part of your dataframe and the desired output.

Comment: I have updated a question